# Comparing Dates & other little java quips

Tags: java, exception

I am currently working on some code that requires a comparison of dates as follows:

```
public int compare(ItemLocation o1, ItemLocation o2) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
                Date date1 = sdf.parse(o1.getDatePublished());
                Date date2 = sdf.parse(o2.getDatePublished());
                Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal1.setTime(date1);
                cal2.setTime(date2);
                if(cal1.equals(cal2)) { 
                    return 0; 
                } else if(cal1.before(cal2)) {
                    return -1;
                } else if(cal1.after(cal2)) {
                    return 1;
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

So my question is muti-part.

1. is this the best method to go about comparing 2 dates?
2. with the "the method must return a result of type int" error msg, what is the best way to go about fixing this? (I don't think that adding a return 0; at the end is very practical...which is what I was thinking)
3. [optional] is there a more efficient way to write the 3 if/else if statements?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the good method to compare dates. 
For the compilation error, rethrow an exception in your catch block or return an int value.

Comment: sorry I'm somewhat new to java still...could you explain the "rethrow an exception in your catch block" ?

Comment: You can either add a "throw e", in which case you'll probably have to declare the exception in the function declaration( and that'd be equivalent to not catching the exception at all) or add "throw new RuntimeException(e)". Either way, that will interrupt you execution flow until some caller catches the exception.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `date1.compareTo(date2)`
2. Compile error: No default return value. See point #1
3. From point #1:

   ```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
   Date date1 = sdf.parse(o1.getDatePublished());
   Date date2 = sdf.parse(o2.getDatePublished());
   return date1.compareTo(date2);
   ```

Comment: yes I was reading an article about the different ways to compare dates and it said that the calendar method is better because if different sdf formats are compared, the compareTo method will return false.

Comment: But you are using the one SimpleDateFormat format here so this is not an issue. :)